# ROOM, OkHttp cache data on device from nowhere?

Tags: android, caching, android-room, okhttp

I am struggling with strange thing.
As I am owner and main developer application TibiaMonsters, I know that there is no sql data or shared preferences where we could have any data to run application without internet on the begging.

So for phone Xiaomi 5+ when I download application and run it without internet, it will ask me to turn on internet to go deeper.
But in phone Huawei P30 Pro when I download application and turn off internet before starting application I have already some data (which should be downloaded first).
Ok so I might have some cache problem, maybe okHttp? (from previous versions of application)
After clearing data/cache - > turning off internet application says I need internet to use it.
(So yeah we dont have any data thats great! - this should happen after installing application on the very begging, we shouldnt be forced to use clearing data/cache)
So I turn on internet, enter to application download newest data. (to update the cache)
But when I uninstall application again and install it and even when I turn off internet before starting application I have again data from nowhere? And to be clear this data isn't the newest one downloaded after clear/cache but it's exacly (old) previous one.

My conjectures..
So I guess somehow I have two caches on my Huawei device. One is very old and another is from current application(but newest one is not existing yet because I dont have internet, so newest cache didn't created yet).
So when I start application without internet, application is using "old" cache and can display some data.
Removing cache gives me avaiable to download newest data. So new cache is creating. When I uninstall application newest cache is deleted but my old cache still exist!?.
Unfortunately I can't check what data is in cache or if I have two caches like I think because I dont have root.

I could do formating phone or hard restart but I don't like this option.

Here I uploaded videos to show exacly how it looks like on two different devices.

Xiaomi (working great!)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IIqugBGQ14Mp942bv6xsyUhXg5e_0ZR0/view?usp=sharing

Huawei (problem)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qh1fT-dl9G1UtehSz1HKwj6gDqsnjl_f/view?usp=sharing

Sample code:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message) {
                Timber.i(message);
            }
        });
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache cache(File cacheFile) {
        return new Cache(cacheFile, 10 * 1000 * 1000);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    File cacheFile(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        return new File(context.getCacheDir(), "okhttp_cache");
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient(Cache cache) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
    }

    public RoomModule(Application application) {
    this.database = Room.databaseBuilder(
            application,
            MonsterDatabase.class,
            "Tibia.db")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build();
    }
```

What do you think guys might be the cache?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have `android:allowBackup` enabled? If so, try to disable it.

Comment: Yes I have, omg this might be the solution. Thanks!